# Ubuntu gnome 16.04 Brightness problem

Tags: gnome, brightness

I've installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 (I resist to use unity... is fugly IMO) but I'm having a problem with the brightness. It's always to bright and it hurts my eyes.

I didnt find any options in the system to fix it so I installed this app, brightness controller, thru the terminal. It kinda works. I mean, I can use a slider to reduce the bright (it's always at 100 so I reduce it to 90).. but from time to time the brightness resets itself and become at 100. Besides, everytime I restart the os the brightness become bright again.

How can I fix it permanently?

I am using a PC. So I do not have that power option in the top corner.

Besides, I have an AMD GPU (R9 280X) and there is no additional driver for this card in ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the right top corner (where there is the audio indicator, network indicator and power/battery indicator) and you'll find two sliders, one for the audio and one for the brightness

[screenshot showing the two sliders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAKtp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that u have already tried default bars in top right corner and they didnt work for u ,do this ->
Press super key or go in appdrawer,
Type driver,
Select additional driver or driver manager,
A window will open 
Select  additional drivers tab,
See if ur display driver is is use or not
If there r no options to display
Make sure that u r connected to internet,
Open terminal and type sudo apt-get upgrade
And then do above procedure again. 
If there is driver auto detected by system but not in use and then select use and apply settings reboot and this should solve ur problem.after that u can use ur default brightness key on keyboard to adjust using fn key or without it. Gud luck :)